# Is it possible to set the runtime path of a program compiled by Pyinstaller to the same as the directory it's executed from?

Tags: python, directory, path, pyinstaller

I've made a simple Python program and compiled it as a single executable file using Pyinstaller, since the users are afraid of terminals.

It looks for a template-file within the folder and simply creates cyclic copies of it with a naming-convention. However, it didn't work as intended after double-clicking the single-file executable.

I noticed that if I ran that very same file from a terminal-window within the same directory, it worked correctly, so I think the problem is that it gets a runtime path outside of this directory. I'm looking for a possible solution to make this program self aware of its path. I tried setting the path using `os.getcwd()` but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: I believe you're looking for [this](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v4.0/runtime-information.html#using-sys-executable-and-sys-argv-0).

Answer (score 0):

try this to get the current directory

```
import os
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
print(dirname)
```